# removable singularity and composition

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: D(P, r) \setminus \{P \} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. and define $U = f(D(P,r) \setminus \{P \})$ be open.

and define $g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic.

If $f$ has a removable singularity at $P$ does $g \circ f$ have one also?

---

My guess is that the properties of $g\circ f$ depends on $g$,

\begin{align}
\lim_{z \rightarrow P} g\left( f(z) \right) =
\end{align}

Comment: You mean $g : f(D(P,r)\setminus\{P\})\to\mathbb C$?

Comment: Why are you looking at $g(\infty)$?  This seems more appropriate if $f$ has a pole, not a removable singularity.  This question may depend on if $\lim_{z\rightarrow P}f(z)\in U$.

Comment: @ YiorgosS.Smyrlis, yes. @ Michael Burr, I got your point.